# Not able to populate ListView from JSON URL (android)

Tags: android, json, listview

Good evening, I'm new to Android development and I'm having issues populating a `ListView` from JSON URL

The parsing is fine though. This is what I have tried so far:

```
try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
        String asef = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
        {

            JSONObject hospital = array.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject hospital2 = hospital.getJSONObject("address");
            if (!hospital2.isNull("hospital")) {
                String hospitalName = hospital2.getString("hospital");
                String hospitalLat = hospital.getString("lat");
                String hospitalLon = hospital.getString("lon");
                hospitals.add("hospitalLat");
            }
        }
}
```

This is my listview

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayList<String> hospitals = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Are you setting an adapter?

Comment: What is your log cat error?

Comment: ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>      (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,hospitals);
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)

Comment: No error just crushing

Comment: I think you going to parse the wrong format JSON parsing, please check sure your JSON format.

Comment: @R.Asakura please post your JSON response.

Comment: i found the problem!!!!
i didnt declared this
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

10th page of google results it is!